# Making a multivariable function in Java

Tags: java, function

I am trying to make a function that I can refer to in my main method. With a double variable input X and string input Y, I want the function to do the following:

```
 BigDecimal bdX = new BigDecimal(X);
 String strX = String.valueOf(bdX.doubleValue());
 strX = strX.replaceAll("E", " x 10^");

 System.out.println("\nOutput = " + strX + Y);
```

In python you could define a function like so:

```
def FunctionName(X,Y) {
//tasks
}
```

How do I do this in Java? And how would I call on it? Thanks!

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_methods.htm

Comment: did any of the answers work? Or you need more help?

Comment: You realize that a method and a function are the same thing...

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to convert `double` to `String`. And If you want to return that `String` then:

```
public static String function(double x, String y) { 
    String strX = Double.toString(x); //String.valueOf(x) would have worked fine too
    strX = strX.replaceAll("E", " x 10^");
    return strX + y;
}
```

Or if you just want to print it out and donot want it to return that `String`, then

```
public static void function(double x, String y) { 
    String strX = Double.toString(x);
    strX = strX.replaceAll("E", " x 10^");
    System.out.println("\nOutput = " + strX + Y);
}
```

Then you will just call the above method in your main method.

ps: I converted `double` to `String` because why take that extra step of converting it to `BigDecimal` first and then convert it to `String`.

Comment: Your first function ignores `y`. The method should probably also be `static` since there's no state.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you!

Comment: @JonathanMousley if this answer helped you consider accepting it please?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood you right, but I try to anser you ^^

If you want to call the method from the main method, you have to make your method static.

It would look like:

```
public static void main(String args) {
    yourMethod(10.0, "Test"); // calls your method with example params
}

public static void yourMethod(double X, String Y) {
    // Your tasks
    BigDecimal bdX = new BigDecimal(X);
    String strX = String.valueOf(bdX.doubleValue());
    strX = strX.replaceAll("E", " x 10^");
    System.out.println("\nOutput = " + strX + Y);
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!